# How Activerecord polymorphic mechanism can be used for MTI implementation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have found this Q-A [Why does ActiveRecord in Rails not support Multiple Table Inheritance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27848263/why-does-activerecord-in-rails-not-support-multiple-table-inheritance)

And now i have a question according to CdotStrifeVII's answer

> Polymorphic associations fill that role for most use cases

do you agree with this?

As for me, polymorphic is more like STI implementation...

How rails polymorphic mechanism can be used to implement MTI?

Comment: Though I can not explain much, I read this article some time ago and found helpful https://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-10-multiple-table-inheritance/